# How can I prevent text from being cut off in a selection box?

Tags: html, css

I have a long option that I need to be properly shown along with the whole selection box. If you set the width to 100% then select the first option, the text gets cut off. When the width is set to auto there is no scrollbar, which is a problem because I need the selection box to fit inside another element.

This code is from a w3schools tutorial that I have been using to check changes because it is faster than using localhost since the website is already up and this is just debugging.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <style>
    #selection {
      width: auto;
      overflow: scroll;
    }
    
    option {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>

  <select id="selection" multiple>
    <option value="volvo">If they are able to help ask them to wash themselves. You may give them step by step instructions such as, 'sit down' 'here is the cloth' 'wash your arm' etc. If they cannot, ask them to ‘help’ by holding the towel.</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just a suggestion... since you need to be able to select multiple items and since you have a long string of text on one of them, a better way to present the options would be a group of checkboxes. You can still grab multiple values from the selected items using JS and it may just look better in general. Plus you'll be able to read that long string of text, which will overflow normally.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will look into it.